# Stateful workflow engine in PHP?

Tags: php, workflow

Anyone knows some state-full work-flow engine in PHP ? I'm talking about the kind also known as document-centric (oriented) or content-centric (oriented). ezC and the like are all activity based and I'm *not* looking for process modeling !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for a while with ezc and FSM PEAR package, I decided to do it myself. So far, so good :)

Answer (score 1):

Does page 43 of Sebastian Bergmann's thesis on ezC and workflow engines help you? There may be some alternative there.

http://sebastian-bergmann.de/publications/bergmann-WorkflowEngine-DiplomaThesis.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[formapro/pvm](https://github.com/formapro/pvm) could be used without persistence storage and with it. There is a mongo storage supported out of the box.

The formapro/pvm also supports parallel task execution (if configured). To use it you need both persistent storage and a message queue library installed and configured.